# How to avoid setTimeout to be overridden?

Tags: javascript, settimeout

I am calling a the function `notifyError()` multiple times and I am trying to find a way not to* override the `setTimeout()` inside it each time.

Instead, I would like to create new *instances* of `setTimeout` each time `notifyError()` is being called.

```
export function notifyError(message) {
  ...

  setTimeout(() => {
    notifications.splice(notification.length -1, 1)
  }, 3000)
}
```

Comment: *"Instead, I would like to create new instances of setTimeout each time notifyError() is being called."* That's what that code does. For instance, if you call `notifyError` three times, three timeouts will be created, each of which will remove the last notification **as of when the timer fires** (which may well not be the notification that was -- I'm guessing -- just put there).

Comment: um, it should not. setTimeout makes an instance and only way you are getting rid of it is to call clearTimeout or you reload the page. Maybe the flaw is the code that the timeout calls.

Comment: `setTimeout()` *always* creates a new timer. What you need to do is save the return value from `setTimeout()` and then *cancel* a previous timer before starting a new one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to guess that in the `...` code, you're putting `message` in `notifications` (directly or in some wrapper) and you're wondering why when you have overlapping calls, the wrong notification gets removed from `notifications`.

It's because each time `notifyError` is called, it schedules a timer to fire three seconds later. Three seconds later when that timer fires, it removes the **last** notification in `notifications`, whether or not that is the notification that relates to that call to `notifyError`.

Instead, remove the notification that was added. For instance, if it's just the string, you can do it like this:

```
export function notifyError(message) {
    // ...
  
    setTimeout(() => {
        const index = notifications.indexOf(message);
        if (index !== -1) {
            notifications.splice(index, 1);
        }
    }, 3000)
}
```

But if what you put in `notifications` is an object or some such, you'll need `findIndex` with an appropriate callback instead (or keep the object and use `indexOf` with the object).